# PostGIS convert GeoJSON to geography

Tags: postgis, geojson, geography-data-type

While there are functions to convert geography to GeoJSON:

[text ST_AsGeoJSON(geography geog, integer maxdecimaldigits=15, integer options=0);](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)

I do not see any way to go the opposite direction (GeoJSON to geography) only to geometry.
http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors

Is this on the roadmap?

---

The data in the database has geography polygons or multi-polygons to describe each item in the DB. The query is coming from lealfet.js, which allows me to easily get the shape in GeoJSON.

What I am doing is just a simple ST_Intersects() to check for overlap and return. Yes, I have a hack to convert this to EWKT right now, but I was wondering if it was on the roadmap to support this in a future version of PostGIS, or where one adds it as a wish list (since symmetry is a good thing, and it seems a shame that only geometry is supported in that direction).

Comment: You're not asking how to (use which nested functions)? Just is the single function solution coming?

Comment: Is your objective to take GeoJSON data from flat files (i.e. outside of the database) and put them into your database? If so, are you aware of the `ogr2ogr` and `shp2pgsql` utilities?

Comment: I added an update to address both these questions. Did I answer them?

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you just do:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojsongoeshere)::geography;
```

Comment: Are you saying that ST_GeogFromGeoJSON is the same as: ST_GeogFromWKB(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(...)))?

[assume the JSON is only polygons in EPSG 4326 format]

Comment: If you are using a different projection than 4326 for geo json, then you would do: 
 
    SELECT   ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojsongoeshere),4326)::geography;  I wouldn't use ST_GeogFromWKB because geometry is technically NOT WKB.  It'll work but geography(geometry) also written as geometry::geography is a more direct conversion.

Comment: I am keeping in all in 4326. Thank you for your expertise.